# Pourquoi dit-on "interprète" et pas "interpréteur " (computing) ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, québec

> Ce type d'outil est désigné en anglais par le terme « interpreter ».
> Souvent, alors que les auteurs du premier livre d'enseignement en
> français sur la théorie des programmes, ont proposé « interprète »,
> cela est souvent traduit en français par le calque « interpréteur »,
> ce terme étant notamment recommandé par l'OQLF. (wiki : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpr%C3%A8te_(informatique)#Terme)

Sans faute de ma part

> *compiler* => *compilateur*

Selon ce modèle

> *interpréter* => *interpréteur*

n'est pas plus logique que *interprète* ? Pourquoi l'OQLF le recommande alors qu'*interpréteur* est considéré un calque de l'anglais ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'utilisation d'un mot différent est peut-être encouragée pour distinguer les deux sens possibles. Un *interprète* est une personne dont c'est le métier ou l'activité, un *interpréteur* est un programme.

On retrouve un peu la même différence entre un *programmeur* (personne) et un *programmateur* (plutôt un instrument).

Pour ce qui est de la logique, l'étymologie permet de comprendre les liens entre verbes et substantifs :

1. compiler →  *compileor/compileur* (moyen français, mot disparu)

   compiler →  compil**ation** →  compil**ateur**
2. interpréter →  interpréteur

   *interpres* (latin) →  interprète

   interpréter →  interprét**ation** →  « interprét**ateur** » (très rare)
3. assembler →  assembleur